# Drupal 7 node object in front page missing

Tags: drupal

i just started using drupal and here is a thing which i simply dont understand. so im writing my own theme derived from the default themes. i enabled the image module to also have featured images for basic pages - so far so good. now in template.php i use the preprocess_page hook to get the image to put into a sort of banner above the page content but .. the node object is not in the first parameter (of the function= but only for the front page?! on all other pages i see the node object. can somebody explain that to me maybe? or does this sound like some self produced thing. i tested the bartik theme and i could reproduce this behavior so i wonder why

thanks

Comment: For Drupal related questions go here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The default front page isn't a node, it's provided by the [`node_page_default()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_page_default/7) function, which is why you don't have a node object available.

Comment: ok got it. the concept of nodes, pages and what not was missing. thanks